# Is there a way to use another location's STATIC IP?

Tags: vpn, static-ip

Trying to connect to RemoteMySQL on my web server.

My web host need to whitelist a single static IP to allow remoteMysql connection.

My dilemma is that at home, where i'm programming 99% of the time, is on a Dynamic, non-public IP address (Mobile Data via LTE).

However, at my office, we do have static IP.

I was wondering if there was a way for me to use my office's Static IP, perhaps via some sort of VPN method through it.

I tried to establish a VPN and then set my Home PC to my Office's gateway but that just broke the VPN connection, lolz.

At the moment i'm just using Remote Desktop to carry out my remoteMysql stuffs, but it's such a pain in the *tooooot*

Regards to all

Answer (score 0):

The only way to use your workplace's static IP is to connect to a VPN inside your workplace network, which would have to be configured in such a way to forward the traffic through the IP address which was whitelisted.

There are many ways you could achieve this, but you should try to get your workplace's network admin to set it up for you.

Comment: that's good to know, but i AM the admin of the office LOL.. this something i've not encountered before and did research , very little (none) is said about something similar.. i guess it's a unique case.

i've vPN'd already to my office no problem.. but i don't have a clue how to forward/trunk traffic through the office's internet connection via VPN.. any ideas then?

Comment: @brownchild you might have better luck asking for further help on serverfault.